# File not found by include statement, but QT Project compiles and runs

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Have set up a QT Project with QT Creator and working on it with CLion. The program compiles and runs, but from the parser it gets an error, that the "./ui_entrywindow" is not found. I don't get this error within the QTCreator.

Any code below was generated by QTCreator. This is the header file, which class and namespace should be included:

```
#ifndef ENTRYWINDOW_H
#define ENTRYWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class EntryWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class EntryWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
 EntryWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
 ~EntryWindow();

 private:
 Ui::EntryWindow *ui;
 };
 #endif // ENTRYWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Qt creator probably added your build tree to its include path. You should do the same.

Comment: How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207253135-CLion-fails-to-find-some-of-my-headers-Where-does-it-search-for-them-